# Site Executing control characters in title tag

Tags: penetration-test, xss, research

I am currently pentesting a site for a client of mine and I found a very strange 'bug'.

They have a search box on the home page which if I enter `te\tst` and hit search, it redirects to the search results page (not via ajax), and in the title it shows the keywords which I searched for, however, the control character actually gets executed.

So the title tag says this: `"te    st | site name"` <-- Executed the \t and created 4 spaces.

So my questions really are:

1. Could this be classed as a potential vulnerability?
2. Is there anyway that this can be exploited?

Thanks!

**[Edit]**

Just FYI, it does also execute other control-characters not just the tab. I just tried \r\n and it new-lined it.

Also, it only executes the control characters if they are encapsulated within other characters, so:

`\r\n` doesn't work
`te\r\nst` will return te[new line]st

Comment: Sounds like maybe they are doing `search.matches("[\w]+")` rather than `search.matches("^[\w]+$")`. As to whether this is exploitable, I'm unsure - it would depend on what other functions the search term is passed through.

Comment: So are you suggesting that this is done via javascript and not on the server side? The reason I ask this, is because it is redirected to a new page, and from experience, it would be much easier (and arguably faster/safer) for me to populate a title tag from the server side over the client side.

I will test this though, I'll read through the (minified) js to see what I can find :)

Comment: I'm not suggesting this is done clientside, it seems likely that the content is simply `POST`ed to the results page, where it is filtered and *used* (The definition of *used* will lead to whether or not this is exploitable). The regex I posted was to explain your very last point about needing 'normal' chars surrounding the control chars.

Comment: Yeah I tested out the regex and you're right, that's why it requires the chars around the control characters. Well I'll carry on poking around and let you know

Comment: Can you make the application parse hex representation like "te\x41st" -> "teAst"? If yes then this can probably used to circumvent some XSS protections (if there is any). Can you display multi-byte characters this way?

Comment: Hi buherator, I just tested the Hex value and yes it does get executed and resolved to its plaintext counter-part. However, the < > characters still get html entitied. Any suggestions?

Comment: Okay I've gotten it executing the XSS payload. If you want to put that into an answer @buherator then I'm more than happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many vulnerabilities occur as a result of smaller non-exploitable bugs which cause different parts of the software make false assumptions about each other.

Returning user-input in a web applications response obviously suggests the possibility of [cross-site scripting (XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) attacks. These can be eliminated by proper input/output filtering/encoding.

Applying a transformation like parsing the control characters you mentioned can however make your payload slip through the applied protections, for example the following pseudocode:

`transform(filter_xss($input))`

can result in valid HTML/JS for the following input:

`test\x3cscript\x3ealert(1)\x3c/script\x3etest`

[Multibyte characters can also be useful for exploitation.](http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2011/07/22/bypassing-validaterequest-in-asp-net/)

Also it seems possible that the user input gets parsed by some kind of command shell that would make more dangerous attacks, namely [command injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection) possible. Based on the operating system you can try different metacharacters to achieve remote code execution, these are some for *nix:

https://web.archive.org/web/20120810003039/https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/help/doc/primer/node109.html